# On Erdős' elementary proof of the asymptotics of the partition function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

My question concerns a step in Erdős' "elementary" proof of $p(n) \sim \frac{a}{n}e^{cn^{\frac{1}{2}}}$, where $p(n)$ is the number of partitions of a natural number $n$ and $c=\pi\sqrt{(2/3)}$. I'll try to present all relevant details from the main [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1968802.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A4b49893a3d5768b53b07f150ef4468c9):

Erdős first proves that $0 < \liminf\frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}} \le \limsup\frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}} < \infty$  as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Next, he proceeds to prove
$$
\liminf\frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}} = \limsup\frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}}
$$
by contradiction: suppose the above does not hold and write

$$
\liminf\frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}} = d, \ \ \ \limsup\frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}} = D
$$
Now choose $n$ large and such that
$$
\frac{np(n)}{e^{cn^{1/2}}} > D-\epsilon
$$
I understand why it is possible to choose such $n$. Here's the step that I'm completely confused by:

Since $p(n)$ is an increasing function of $n$, there exists a $c_2$ such that for every $m$ in the range $n\le m\le n + c_2n^{1/2}$

$$
\frac{mp(m)}{e^{cm^{1/2}}} > \frac{D + d}{2}
$$

Why does the monotonicity of $p(n)$ imply the existence of such a $c_2$?

Comment: Just FYI, you can find a treatment of Erdos' proof in Nathanson's book Elementary Methods in Number Theory.

Comment: @Teddy38 I have gone through Nathanson's book, but he only proves $\log p(n) \sim cn^{1/2}$, which I nevertheless found helpful since Erdos deemed the proof "easy" and did not write it in full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then $\frac{mp(m)}{e^{cm^{1/2}}} \geq \frac{np(n)}{e^{c\sqrt{n+c_2\sqrt{n}}}} > (D-\epsilon)e^{-c(\sqrt{n+c_2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n})}$.

Now, $\sqrt{n+c_2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{c_2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+c_2\sqrt{n}}} \leq \frac{c_2}{2}$, and thus (if $n \leq m \leq n+c_2n^{1/2}$) we have $\frac{mp(m)}{e^{cm^{1/2}}}> (D-\epsilon)e^{-cc_2/2}$. Now, if $c_2,\epsilon$ are small enough, $(D-\epsilon)e^{-cc_2/2} \geq \frac{D+d}{2}$.

Comment: What amazing technical power! Thank you!